# Symbolic Formulae for Linear Mixed Models

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I would like to understand how to create a good formula for a linear mixed model, using the `Machines` data set  from the package `nlme` as an example:

> Data on an experiment to compare three brands of machines used in an industrial process are presented in Milliken and Johnson (p. 285, 1992). Six workers were chosen randomly among the employees of a factory to operate each machine three times. The response is an overall productivity score taking into account the number and quality of components produced.

The model would look like this in lme4:

```r
lmer(score ~ Machine + (1 | Worker) + (1 | Worker:Machine), data = Machines)
```

The corresponding Formula would then look like this:

$Y_{ijk}=\mu+\alpha_i+\beta_j+(\alpha\beta)_{ij}+\epsilon_{ij}$

- where $\alpha_i$ is the fixed effect of machine $i$ (with the usual side constraint)
- $\beta_j$ is the random effect of worker $j$
- $(\alpha\beta)_{ij}$ is the corresponding (random) interaction
- and $\epsilon_{ij}$ is the residula error

How would I have to change this formula if I wanted to and an additional Factor (e.g. sex) with only two levels and therefore explicitly without the random effect `(1|Sex)`, just with the interaction `(1 | Worker:Sex)`.

Like in this model:

```r
lmer(score ~ Machine + (1 | Worker) + (1 | Worker:Machine) + (1 | Worker:Sex), data = Machines)
```

Would the Formula then change to this:

$Y_{ijk}=\mu+\alpha_i+\beta_j+(\alpha\beta)_{ij}+(\beta\gamma)_{jk}+\epsilon_{ijk}$

- where $(\beta\gamma)_{jk}$ is the (random) interaction between Worker and Sex

Or is this the wrong approach?

Comment: Why not include `Sex` as a fixed effect?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen In the Example it would totaly make sense, however in my real Formula which I wanted to abstract with the example this is not possible since Machine can be seen as nested in sex so I can't use it as a fixed effect and for a random effect I suppose sex has to less levels (rule of thumb > 5).